# Creating a SingleBlockingQueue Synchronizer

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to create a `SingleBlockingQueue<T>` synchronizer that allows one thread to `offer()` an element to it, and another thread that will `take()` it. Only one `T` element is held inside the `SingleBlockingQueue<T>` at a time, and the pushing thread is blocked  on `offer()` if the previous element is waiting for the taking thread to `take()` it. The pushing thread will keep pushing items until it calls `setComplete()`, and the taking thread will keep calling `take()` while `isComplete()` is false. The taking thread will block if it is waiting for an element.

Here is the synchronizer I've got so far.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public final class SingleBlockingQueue<T> {

    private volatile T value;
    private final AtomicBoolean isComplete = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final AtomicBoolean isPresent =  new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void offer(T value) throws InterruptedException {
        while (isPresent.get()) {
            this.wait();
        }
        this.value = value;
        synchronized(this) {
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    public boolean isComplete() {
        return !isPresent.get() && isComplete.get();
    }
    public void setComplete() {
        isComplete.set(true);
    }
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (!isPresent.get()) {
            this.wait();
        }
        T returnValue = value;
        isPresent.set(false);
        synchronized(this) {
            this.notifyAll();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Here is a usage example in Kotlin

```
    val queue = SingleBlockingQueue<Int>()

    thread {
        for (i in 1..1000) {
            queue.offer(i)
        }
        queue.setComplete()
    }

    thread {
        while (!queue.isComplete) {
            println(queue.take())
        }
    }

    Thread.sleep(100000)
```

However, I am getting an error and I'm a bit in over my head at this point. I haven't made synchronizers in a long time thanks to RxJava. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.swa.rm.common.util.SingleBlockingQueue.take(SingleBlockingQueue.java:29)
    at RxOperatorTest$testSingleBlockingQueue$2.invoke(RxOperatorTest.kt:33)
    at RxOperatorTest$testSingleBlockingQueue$2.invoke(RxOperatorTest.kt:8)
    at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:18)
```

Comment: Shouldn't wait() be called within a synchronized block?

Comment: I tried that but had same issues. Maybe I need to create two independent locks? Also, didn't do that for this synchronizer I wrote awhile ago and didn't have any issues. https://github.com/thomasnield/tom-sync/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nield/concurrency/BufferedLatch.java

Comment: that github code gives the same error if I directly call await() [Just tried in my local eclipse]. May be you have a lock on the monitor associated with that object before calling await().

Comment: Alright I will need to struggle a bit more, and I suspect there might be gaps in my synchronization :(

Comment: Maybe I need to make one lock for putting and another for taking...

Comment: Firstly are you trying to learn by creating this? Java already has a blocking queue. If you are trying to learn you could use 2 semaphores to signal between threads [writer initialized to 1 and reader to 0]. You could use wait/notify as well but better use the new constructs. Also in your code isPresent is initialized to "false" and never set to "true".

Comment: Haha well that might be a problem. I'm always learning but I am trying to bridge an RxJava Observable to an Iterator serially. This synchronizer is the key. I'll play with the sempahore idea later as those feel appropriate for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you could use the existing implementation in `SynchronousQueue`.

If you want to implement your own, you are pretty close, you just need to make sure the calls to `wait()` are inside the `synchronized` block.

Unfortunately, I believe the `isComplete()` / `setComplete()` mechanism in your original code is subject to a race condition, as `setComplete()` may be called after `isComplete()` has returned `false` and before or even while the reading thread is executing `take()`.  This would potentially hang the reading thread.

```
  public final class SingleBlockingQueue<T> {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private T value;
    private boolean present = false;

    public void offer(T value) throws InterruptedException {
      synchronized (lock) {
        while (present)
          lock.wait();
        this.value = value;
        present = true;
        lock.notifyAll();
      }
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
      synchronized (lock) {
        while (!present)
          lock.wait();
        T returnValue = value;
        value = null; // Should release reference
        present = false;
        lock.notifyAll();
        return returnValue;
      }
    }
  }
```

For comparison, it may be more natural to implement this kind of queue based on `Semaphore` or `Condition` objects.  Here is an implementation using a pair of semaphores to signal empty/full conditions.

```
  public final class SingleBlockingQueue<T> {
    private volatile T value;
    private final Semaphore full = new Semaphore(0);
    private final Semaphore empty = new Semaphore(1);

    public void offer(T value) throws InterruptedException {
      empty.acquire();
      this.value = value;
      full.release();
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
      full.acquire();
      T returnValue = value;
      value = null; // Should release reference
      empty.release();
      return returnValue;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `Semaphore` approach is beautifully simple, thank you. One last question. How do I safely communicate there are no more items? I positively tested the bejeezus out of this using an `AtomicBoolean` on the client side, but I still am wary.

Comment: Here is my usage in Kotlin. Although I couldn't prove it, I worry the last element call on `take()` could get skipped https://gist.github.com/thomasnield/a3f7981ea447e0c049ba5943afa44fb8#file-singleblockingqueue-usage-kt

Comment: Ha, proved my concern was correct. I updated my gist with a `sleep()` and  a comment showing where this could derail.

Comment: I think I fixed it with a small modification. https://gist.github.com/thomasnield/2d07d2324159aa5debd714759d7e7876#file-singeblockingqueue-java

Comment: Let me think about the termination condition.  The additional problem that I see is that  there is no guarantee that the reading thread won't already have called `take()` and be waiting in (for example) `full.acquire()` at the time that the completion flag is set.  I think you could trigger this in your test by putting a `Thread.sleep(100)` before calling `isDone.set(true)` and removing the existing sleep.

Comment: One possible way to synchronize completion would be to use a sentinel value.  Once the writer had completed writing all the actual values, it could write the sentinel value which the reader could check for and stop once read.  You could use (cough) `null` for this, or some other arbitrary, otherwise unused value.  Something like `while ((value = q.take()) != null) doStuff(value);`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to implement it yourself you can use  `SynchronousQueue`

References:

[SynchronousQueue javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/synchronousqueue.html

> The SynchronousQueue class implements the BlockingQueue interface.
>   Read the BlockingQueue text for more information about the interface.
>
> The SynchronousQueue is a queue that can only contain a single element
>   internally. A thread inseting an element into the queue is blocked
>   until another thread takes that element from the queue. Likewise, if a
>   thread tries to take an element and no element is currently present,
>   that thread is blocked until a thread insert an element into the
>   queue.

Comment: The Javadoc description of `SynchronousQueue` is misleading it does _not_ have the capacity to store one element:  It's capacity is _zero_.  The description of the behavior is key:  The producer thread can't just `put()` an element and walk away.  Any `q.put(e)` call is blocked until a consumer calls `q.take()`.   That makes `SynchronousQueue` behave differently from what the OP described.  (Of course, whether it's different from what the OP actually _wants_ is an entirely different question.)

Comment: Yes, I wan the `put()` to be blocked if it is waiting for a `take()` to remove the single element and free the slot.

Comment: Actually, the documentation in the Java8 JDK says, "A synchronous queue does not have any internal capacity, _not even a capacity of one._"  (emphasis, mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a note I had some issues with the `ResultSet` jumping forward due to timing of `next()` calls in RxJava-JDBC framework. I went with this implementation modifying the answers previously given.

```
public final class SingleBlockingQueue<T> {
    private volatile T value;
    private final Semaphore nextGate = new Semaphore(0);
    private final Semaphore waitGate = new Semaphore(0);

    private volatile boolean hasValue = true;
    private volatile boolean isFirst = true;

    public void offer(T value) throws InterruptedException {
        if (isFirst) {
            nextGate.acquire();
            isFirst = false;
        }
        this.value = value;
        waitGate.release();
        nextGate.acquire();
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        T returnValue = value;
        value = null; // Should release reference
        return returnValue;
    }
    public boolean next() throws InterruptedException {
        nextGate.release();
        waitGate.acquire();
        return hasValue;
    }
    public void setDone() {
        hasValue = false;
        waitGate.release();
    }
}
```

This is what I was using it for: turning an RxJava `Observable<T>` into a `Sequence<T>` in Kotlin.

```
import com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.QuerySelect
import rx.Observable
import rx.Scheduler
import rx.lang.kotlin.subscribeWith
import java.io.Closeable

class ObservableIterator<T>(
        observable: Observable<T>
) : Iterator<T>, Closeable {

    private val queue = SingleBlockingQueue<T>()

    private val subscription =
            observable
                    .subscribeWith {
                        onNext { queue.offer(it) }
                        onCompleted { queue.setDone() }
                        onError { queue.setDone() }
                    }

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
        return queue.next()
    }

    override fun next(): T {
        return queue.take()
    }
    override fun close() {
        subscription.unsubscribe()
        queue.setDone()
    }
}

fun <T> Observable<T>.asSequence() = ObservableIterator(this).asSequence()

fun QuerySelect.Builder.asSequence(scheduler: Scheduler) = get { it }
        .subscribeOn(scheduler)
        .asSequence()
```

Comment: Note that when returned `Sequence` isn't consumed entirely, the subscription to the observable would block forever in `onNext`.